# Construct a deductive system where $1^n$ is provable iff n is not prime

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, formal-languages, formal-proofs

I'd appreciate some help for the following exercise:

Construct a (as simple as possible) deductive system where all sequences of the form 1n
(which means 111... n-times) is provable if and only if n is not prime. (Note: As simple as possible means that the deductive rules and axioms should follow a simple schema. For example the schema "1n

is an axiom iff n is prime" isn't considered simple)

There is already an answered question to the problem of finding a similar deductive system in case n is not prime. 
[Construct a deductive system where $1^n$ is provable iff $n$ is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973290/construct-a-deductive-system-where-1n-is-provable-iff-n-is-prime)
I am also interested in the solution to that problem, because I don't understand the notation in the answer (i.e. I don't know, what lt, ndiv, ndivsmaller etc means) and I can't simply write a comment there to clear that, because my reputation isn't high enough to do so yet.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove a number $n$ is **not** prime it suffices to provide a divisor greater than 1, and less than $n$.

Interpret $1^n : 1^m :: 1^k$ to mean that $n \times m = k$
Interpret $1^k$ to mean $k$ is composite.

Axiom
$$1^n : 1 :: 1^n$$

Deduction Rules
1. $ 1^n : 1^m :: 1^k \rightarrow 1^m : 1^n :: 1^k$
2. $1^n : 1^m :: 1^k \rightarrow 1^n : 1^{m+1} :: 1^{k+n}$
3. $1^{2+n} : 1^{2+m} :: 1^k \rightarrow 1^k$ with  $n \ge 0, m \ge 0$

Here is a proof that 4 is composite:
Axiom
$$11:1::11$$
Rule 2
$$11:11::1111$$

Rule 3 
$$1111$$

Comment: Thank you! You really seem to know your stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Note: This system is for proving that numbers **are** prime, but the question was later changed to ask the opposite.

Interpret the string $1^n | 1^m$ to mean that $\gcd (n, m) = 1$
Interpret the string $1^n || 1^m$ to mean that $\gcd(n, m') = 1$ for all $1 \le m' \le m$
Intepret $1^n : 1^m :: 1^k$ to mean that there exists an integer solution in $a,b$ of $a\times n + b\times m = k$.
And of course $1^n$ means $n$ is prime.

Let $\epsilon = 1^0$ be the empty string.

Axioms:
$$ 1^n : 1^m :: \epsilon$$ 
$$ 1^n || \epsilon$$

Deduction rules:
1. Symmetry $1^n : 1^m :: 1^k \rightarrow 1^m : 1^n :: 1^k$
2. Adding to both sides $1^n : 1^m :: 1^k \rightarrow 1^n : 1^m :: 1^{k+n}$
3. Subtracting from both sides $1^n : 1^m :: 1^{n+k} \rightarrow 1^n : 1^m :: 1^k$
4. Bezout $1^n : 1^m :: 1 \rightarrow 1^n | 1^m$
5. $1^n || 1^m, \,1^n | 1^{m+1}$ $\rightarrow$ $1^n || 1^{m+1}$
6. $1^{n+1} || 1^{n} \rightarrow 1^{n+1}$

Here is the proof of the string $11$ which means "2 is prime".

First axiom
$$11 : 1: \epsilon$$

Rule 2
$$11 : 1: 1 $$

Rule 4
$$11 | 1$$

Second axiom
$$11 || \epsilon$$

Rule 5 + Previous line
$$11 || 1$$

Rule 6
$$11$$

Here is a proof of $111$ which means 3 is prime.

Lemma 1. $111 | 1$
$$111 : 1 : \epsilon$$
$$111 : 1 : 1$$
$$111 | 1$$

Lemma 2. $111 | 11$
$$111 : 11 : \epsilon$$
$$111 : 11 : 11$$
$$111 : 11 : 1111$$
$$111 : 11 : 1$$
$$111 | 11$$

Now apply rule 5 twice, and then rule 6
$$ 111 || 1 $$
$$ 111 || 11$$
$$ 111$$

Comment: Actually let me try out some proofs to see if this system is correct

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Please let me know if you find an error. \\
And sorry for the confusion about the title. I meant to open a thread for "n is not prime", but wrote in the description "n is prime". (I am interested in the solution to both problems anyways.)
Should I change the title to "n is prime" now so that your answer belongs here?

Comment: I tried to answer the question as it was asked in the body. I'll just add a note at the top of my answer clarifying.

Comment: I did some proofs using the system and I think it works. I'll think if I can modify it to prove non-primes

Comment: Thank you so much! I think you have a few typos in the proofs, but it is clear what you mean. 
Could you explain (not necessarily in detail) what you were thinking to come up with the Axioms and Rules needed?

Comment: Axioms 1 2 and 3 encode some basic rules of arithmetic in the natural numbers. Rule 4 is a statement of the converse of Bezout's Identity applied to gcd(n,m)=1. But in that case, it means that n and m are coprime. Rule 5 and 6 allows you to collapse a list of statements of coprimeness into a single statement, like I did for the 3 is prime proof. The reason I wanted to use Bezout's Identity is to avoid directly trying to encode the concept of non-divisibility. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also the symbols are arbitrary. Except for the double bar $||$ which I decided because it's just an "extra strong" version of the single bar $|$

Comment: Your answers helped me a lot to understand this, Mark. Thank you!